# Reset rails_admin field value

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, field, rails-admin

I want to do a current number, rather than a proper database id field in the list view on my dashboard. For this, I am using `formatted_value` from `rails_admin`. The only thing is, I want to reset that value after the form is rendered, because after I reload the page, that id keeps incrementing, and never goes back to 0. How can I reset the `formatted_value` on a field in rails admin. So far I tried this without much luck:

`config/initializers/rails_admin.rb`

```
  currentId = 0
  # Fields in Projects list
  config.model 'Project' do
    list do
      field :id do
        formatted_value do
          currentId += 1
        end
      end
      field :year
      field :title
      field :intro
      field :description
      field :confidential
      field :star
      field :image
    end
    currentId = 0
```

Comment: it is unclear for me what you asking.

Comment: @Зелёный I have now updated the question with more details. I just want to reset that field once the page has loaded and displayed all of those entries

Comment: you can't _reset_ ruby variable _after_ the form is rendered. Use javascript to manipulate rendered html.

Comment: And can you provide an example on how to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Use search, internet has a lot of examples.

Comment: That's why I asked the question here, because I couldn't find anything that could solve this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128262/discussion-between-vlad-balanescu-and-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED]

I left the `field :id` in the initializer and overrid `app/views/rails_admin/main/index.html.haml with`

```
%th.last.shrink
  %tbody
    - currentId = 1
    - @objects.each do |object|
      %tr{class: "#{@abstract_model.param_key}_row"}
        %td
          = check_box_tag "bulk_ids[]", object.id, false
        - if @other_left_link ||= other_left && index_path(params.except('set').merge(params[:set].to_i != 1 ? {set: (params[:set].to_i - 1)} : {}))
          %td.other.left= link_to "...", @other_left_link, class: 'pjax'
        - properties.map{ |property| property.bind(:object, object) }.each do |property|
          - if property.name.to_s == "id"
            - value = currentId
            - currentId += 1
          - else
            - value = property.pretty_value
```